# ExtJS4 modularization with stand-alone controllers?

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs-mvc

I'm trying to split an ExtJS4 application into modules.

```
 - app
  - store
  - controller
  - model
  - view
  - module
     - m1
         - model
         - view
         - controller
     - m2
         - model
         - ...
```

The problem is, when I start the application and it inits one of the m1 controllers, the controller has no this.control() function.

-- edit --

I defined a class inside of the controller folder.

```
Ext.define( 'App.module.ping.controller.Ping', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

  requires: [
     'App.module.ping.view.PingPanel'
  ],

  init: function() {
     this.control( {
        '#app.module.ping': {
           render: this.onPanelRendered
        }
     } );
  },

  onPanelRendered: function() {
     ...
  }
```

} );

Later I call

```
Ext.create('App.module.ping.controller.Ping').init();
```

but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'control' of undefined
Ext.define.control./lib/extjs-4.1.0/src/app/Controller.js:414
Ext.define.init./app/module/ping/app/controller/Ping.js:11
Ext.define.init./app/module/ping/app/Module.js:11
(anonymous function)app.js:17
(anonymous function)app.js:35
```

Module.js is the file with the create() call
Ping.js is the file with the define() call

-- edit2 --

Pathological example:

input:

```
Ext.define( 'MyController', { 
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller', 
  init: function() { console.log('initialized'); } 
});
```

output:

```
function constructor() {
  return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

input:

```
Ext.create('MyController');
```

output:

```
constructor
```

input:

```
MyController.create();
```

output:

```
constructor
```

-- edit3 --

The controllers require the application object in the config object when created. The application object adds itself to all the controllers, which are *not* manually created with create. It calls something like this:

```
Ext.create('App.controller.Users', { application: this, ... } );
```

Later it uses the application object to redirect the control call to it.

```
control: function ( config ) { this.application.control( config ) };
```

So I'm probably gonna implement some mechanism, which adds the application to those controllers automatically, when I create them.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'controller has no control() function? Can you post some of your code where it happens?

Comment: the error msg doesn't help me. control gets called on this, but it says this is undefined... wat?!

Comment: Congrats on discovering the solution! May be it will lean you back on using their preferred approach to organize source code :) I found that ExtJs relies on directory structure in several places and decided not to invent anything and organize things as they suggest.

Comment: But I want app/module1/controller and not app/controller/module1... their preferred approach I will also get app/view/module1 app/model/module1 etc. I just want one directory which contains all the stuff a module needs to get plugged into some other application and to run stand-alone :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
var pingController = Application.getController('App.module.ping.controller.Ping');
pingController.init(); //or pingController.init(Application);
```

where Application is a reference to the object created during Ext.application.launch - such as

```
var Application = {};
Ext.application({
    //all of your settings,
    launch:function(){
         Application = this;
         //other launch code
    }
}
});
```

Comment: this worked too, thank you! It's even better than my solution, because I don't have to carry the application object around.

Comment: Is it a good idea to call this in the corresponding view? So the main module Controller will only be loaded if a view needs it.

Comment: Which view?  I'm not sure how ExtJS behaves when you create a View and then later create the controller than should control that view.  I generally create the Controller (C) and then immediately after that create the Views that (C) controls.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But it would be nice to just add a view somewhere with it's xtype and some initialization controller gets loaded by the view. With this approach the application which uses the module doesn't have to know how the module works.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone else who comes here searching for a solution to:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'control' of undefined
```

Day long frustration aside, the above answer did not solve my problem, but lead me to try the following, which did fix the issue:

```
// app.js
Ext.application({
    ...

    launch: function(){
        var me = this;
        ...

        me.getController('ControllerName');
    }
});

// inside controller/ControllerName.js
init: function(app){
    var me = this;

    app.control({
        '#editButton': {
            click: function(){
                me.someFunction();
            }
        }
    });
},
```

That app variable is the same as the "var Application = {}" that's in the chosen answer for the question -- meaning I didn't need to add it globally (or at all). I must've tried a million different things, but this finally worked. Hope it saves someone else.

Comment: haha, old question :D I switched to DeftJS later, because their concept of view-controllers was a better fit for my module system.

Comment: Good to know! Mine was more of a case of dynamic controllers getting bogged and weird. This is the only post I found that was remotely similar to my issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to call `init(`) manually. Just call `Ext.create` and constructor will be called automatically.

Comment: I put a log() into the init(). If I call it manually, I get the log-output and the mentioned error. If I just call create() I don't get the output at all.

Comment: Even if you call it like this: `c = Ext.create('App.module.ping.controller.Ping', {});`?

Comment: Yes. I debugged everything that happens in the create() call and never got to init(). Maybe it's a ExtJS 4.1 behaviour?

Comment: Ough... Is it 4.1? I'm still on 4.0.7... What if you create it as `c = App.module.ping.controller.Ping.Create();`?